# SQL sum-function and count-function over several tables result in multiplied values

Tags: sql

After driving myself crazy by countless attempts, I turn to you and hope someone is willing to help me....

I have 4 tables: SO (ServiceOrder), PR (PreRecording), IH (InvoiceHeader) and IL (InvoiceLine), with the columns and rows like underneath:

SO (ServiceOrder):

| SO.No_ |
| --- |
| SO2101234 |
| SO2101235 |
| SO2101237 |
| SO2101239 |

PR (PreRecording):

| PR.No_ | PR.Line | PR.Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SO2101234 | 1 | 50 |
| SO2101234 | 2 | 18 |
| SO2101239 | 1 | 110 |
| SO2101239 | 2 | 40 |
| SO2101239 | 3 | 40 |

IH (InvoiceHeader):

| IH.No_ | IH.SO |
| --- | --- |
| VF2134889 | SO2101234 |
| VF2134890 | SO2101235 |
| VF2134891 | SO2101239 |
| VF2134892 | SO2101234 |
| VF2134893 | SO2101239 |

IL (InvoiceLine):

| IL.DocNo_ | IL.LineNo | IL.LineAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VF2134889 | 1 | 55 |
| VF2134889 | 2 | 23 |
| VF2134890 | 1 | 12 |
| VF2134890 | 2 | 34 |
| VF2134890 | 3 | 87 |
| VF2134891 | 1 | 114 |
| VF2134892 | 1 | 53 |
| VF2134892 | 2 | 25 |
| VF2134892 | 3 | 17 |
| VF2134892 | 4 | 15 |
| VF2134893 | 1 | 43 |
| VF2134893 | 2 | 38 |

Relations:

- `PR.No_` = `SO.No_`
- `IH.SO` = `SO.No_`
- `IL.DocNo_` = `IH.No_`

Desired outcome:

| SO.No_ | PR.SumAmount | IH.SumAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SO2101234 | 68 | 188 |
| SO2101235 | 0 | 133 |
| SO2101237 | 0 | 0 |
| SO2101239 | 190 | 195 |

With my usual simple inner/outer/joins I don't succeed, it's clear that some `SELECT`'s should be nested. With a simple query to combine `SO` and `PR`, I have no problem. With a simple query to combine `SO` and `IH`, I have no problem. However, when I try to setup a query to get all of this in one output, it gets messed up and values start to multiply due to the rows that are used/found in the several tables.

Many thanks in advance....

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: ok, thanks, modified the question....

Comment: Much better now!

Comment: Please also tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply nest your queries so that you do the outer `SELECT` from a flat inner `SELECT`. This will also work if your RDBMS version does not support `WITH` CTEs.

To preserve the rows with `NULL` values, I used `LEFT JOINS` and additionally the [`COALESCE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) function to get `0` as result instead of `NULL`, as in your desired outcome.

```
   SELECT PRGRP.No_, 
          COALESCE(PRGRP.SumAmount, 0) AS PRAmount,
          COALESCE(SUM(IL.LineAmount), 0) AS ILAmount
     FROM (   SELECT SO.No_, SUM(PR.Amount) AS SumAmount
                FROM ServiceOrder SO 
           LEFT JOIN PreRecording PR 
                  ON PR.No_ = SO.No_
            GROUP BY SO.No_
          ) PRGRP
LEFT JOIN InvoiceHeader IH 
       ON IH.SO = PRGRP.No_
LEFT JOIN InvoiceLine IL 
       ON IL.DocNo_ = IH.No_
 GROUP BY PRGRP.No_
```

Result:

| No_ | PRAmount | ILAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SO2101234 | 68 | 188 |
| SO2101235 | 0 | 133 |
| SO2101237 | 0 | 0 |
| SO2101239 | 190 | 195 |

[Full MySQL example in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f483d25d7c6aba795ceedfba6b60c156).

Answer (score 1):

A simple strategy is to flatten the result before doing other lookups. I don't fully grasp what you need to return here but this is the general idea.

```
with SOPR as (
    /* first-level aggregated results */
    select SO.No_, sum(PR.Amount) as PRAmount
    from SO inner join PR on PR.No_ = SO.No_
    group by SO.No_
)
select
    SOPR.No_, min(SOPR.PRAmount) as PRAmount,
    sum(IL.Amount) as ILAmount
/* now look up next level of details */
from SOPR
    inner join IH on IH.SO = SOPR.No_
    inner join IL on IL.DocNo_ = IH.No_
group by SOPR.No_
```

Comment: As far as I can reproduce this code with the "real" table column and row names, this results in output with only rows that have a value <> 0 in ILAmount. It doesn't show rows that only have a value in PRAmount.

Comment: @Evisser It sounds like you may have empty invoices or something which is where left joins come into play rather than the inner joins I wrote based on the sample data.

Comment: No empty invoices. However, there are SO rows without an invoice (SO2101237), like there are SO rows with multiple invoices (SO2101234/SO2101239)